# How can I have a pointer to default struct object in a single statement?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I can first get a default struct object and then a pointer to it.
But I suspect there must be some graceful way to do it; probably in a single statement.

```
auto defaultStructObject = SomeStruct{};
auto pointerToDefaultStructObject = &defaultStructObject;
```

Comment: use rvalue reference &&

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate the line `auto defaultStructObject = SomeStruct{};` and you just want a pointer?

Comment: `SomeStruct{};` is a rvalue you need to extend it's life or it will be destroyed at the end of the full expression; if you could take it's address you would get a dangling pointer.  You can extend it's life with an rvalue reference or a const reference eg `auto && refToDefaultStructObject = SomeStruct{};`

Comment: If your class has no arg constructor you can probably do this auto* pointerToMyStructObj = new MyStruct{};

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
auto defaultStructObject = SomeStruct{}, *pointerToDefaultStructObject = &defaultStructObject;
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/cu8MSJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the first line inside the main function.

```
class MyClass {
    
    public:
    
    MyClass() {};
    void Print() const {std::cout << "hello world \n";}
};

int main() {
   
    auto* pObj = new MyClass();
    pObj->Print();
    return 0;
}
```